# Visual studio 2015. How get project name in code at compile time?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Can I get the name of the file using a macro `__FILE__`.
How to get the name of the project?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b0084kay.aspx

Comment: What do you need that for?

Comment: Project > Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions.  Add `PROJECTNAME=$(ProjectName)`.  Repeat for the Release configuration.

Comment: @HansPassant, there is also a useful switch in the configuration editor for editing all configurations at once.

Comment: You ought to try it to see the havoc it causes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple example on how to do it:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#if !defined PROJECT_NAME
#define PROJECT_NAME ""
#endif

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::string str(PROJECT_NAME);
    std::cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

In the Preprocessor Definitions option of the project properties add the following to the end of the already present definitions:

PROJECT_NAME="$(ProjectName)";

Answer (score 1):

Just add a compiler definition in the project settings. Project name is obviously project-wide, so it should be easy.

You can also use the `$(ProjectName)` build-system macro (available macros can be seen when editing the preprocessor definitions using `<Edit..>` in the drop-down on the value) and put the definition in a property-sheet that you include in all your projects.

Comment: You can find the macros here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx

Comment: @neohope, Yes. However, looking them up inside visual studio has two advantages: you see the values and you also see the ones defined by other components of the system like the SDK and MSBuild.

Answer (score 1):

In c++ the argv[0] is the executable name. Generally executable name is set as project name if you have used default project settings.

```
 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
    std::cout<<"Application name :"<< argv[0]<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OP wanted to have it compile-time, so this isn't a solution.

Comment: It's not reliable way.